# Graphics Glitch while using Ubuntu 22.04 on iMac Late 2009 (NVIDIA 9400m)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, mac

I recently replaced the operating system on my late 2009 iMac with Ubuntu 22.04. It was freezing constantly, so I installed NVIDIA's 340.xx Legacy drivers via terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-340
sudo reboot
```

I then added this to a config file so I wouldn't get a black screen on boot:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf
```

and pasted this, and then saved the file

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GEFORCE 9400M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

This fixed one problem, and created another. There are now 10-15 rows of glitchy pixels in the upper thirds of the dock. I am not using a custom dock.

Any help would be appreciated,

- Toby

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not the best choice for an old computer. Try Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu-Mate instead.

The PPA you've used makes the 340 driver installable, but it has not been tested with or optimized for newer kernels, so bugs should be expected. Nvidia depricated the 340 driver at the end of 2019. It is available in the 20.04 release, and works well with kernel 5.4.

Old drivers need patches to work with newer OSs, but that is not easy with closed Nvidia drivers, ...not much anyone can do.

Comment: Are you saying that changing the kernel from 5.15 to 5.4 would fix the issue? I can't use a different distro.

Comment: No. I know it works in 20.04, kernel 5.4. Wether it works in 22.04 needs testing.

Comment: I installed kernel version 5.4.0 via mainline, but am unsure how to switch from 5.15 to 5.4 (I realize that this is not a probable solution, however I was curious to see what would happen). Also, will switching change Ubuntu's appearance?

Comment: The 340 driver doesn't work well with the 5.4 kernel in ubuntu 20.04, it works about the same -- you get a row of glitchy stuff near the bottom of the screen that sounds very much like the asker's description of what they are seeing in 22.04

Comment: I don't have a doc - not a myMac user here - but I've never seen such a glich, having used an MSI notebook with Geforce 9300M and 340 driver for some years. In fact, the machine is still here, but not used much, and there aren't any glitches. Perhaps there is a bug related to myMacs only.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this on Ubuntu 22.04, but as a workaround for the distractingness of nearly constant similar glitching near the bottom of the screen on my MacBook6,1 in 20.04, I got rid of that the hard way by cutting off 2 rows of output (idea courtesy of the discussion at https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/161#issuecomment-586066197 suggesting they use underscan 1).

Fragment to go in `xorg.conf.d` (adjust the sizes to suit your resolution rather than 1280x800):

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select @1280x798 +0+0 {viewportout=1280x798+0+0}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```